# multi-site web farm for IIS

Tags: iis-7, load-balancing, high-availability

I am having a terrible time finding information on this and I am hoping someone here can help or point me in the right direction.  I am working on a project of setting up an IIS webfarm that is multi-site - that is, example.com will be hosted from location A and location B in high availability or load balancing.

I currently have an IIS farm in test that is working fine, but it is in the same geographical location and thus a single public IP address to access it from the outside.  I am stumped as to how I can have two public IP addresses, one for each geographical site, and make the environment highly available.

If I haven't explained my environment thoroughly, please let me know.  This is my first foray into this sort of thing and just trying to do my best.

Thank you,

Comment: Thanks Nathan.  That's a pretty good start.  I am concerned though because it discusses the use of Global Load Balancing for DNS servers which has the problem of clients caching the hostname resolution.  Is there a solution that fixes this problem?  I ran into another (very old) thread that discusses this same caching problem.  Is there not a better solution?  Thanks again!

Comment: The low TTL values on DNS names will take care of the caching problem.

Comment: I read that browser caching and DNS caching servers ignores the TTL values?  I did find another source that suggests a feature of GSLB is responding to hostname resolution requests with both public IP addresses for the clients to so they can find the available websites on their own.  Can you confirm?

Comment: GSLB won't help you because of browser caching. Virtually the only way to assure "decent" uptime is to have short TTLs and hope for the best since browser caches will snag you every time.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to fix global loadbalancing on your network layer. Probably with some help from your network folks.

Is it a requirement to run your site off your onw infrastructure? If not Windows Azure or Amazone EC2 can help you gain scaialbility and geographical proximity. It is probably easier to use one of these services than doing it yourself.

/Joakim

Comment: For my purposes I have to run my sites off our infrastructure.  We have used EC2 services before, but since we already have the multiple sites for other service redundancy we might as well use it for the websites too.  Could you provide some information on global loadbalancing?  Thanks for your input!